# Call function in itself in callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

i am not quite sure that Title related to my problem, so sorry.

I have asynchronous function that call callback function. So the main idea is I want to call function "dodo" each time after "asyncFunc" is done.

Are there some patterns for that? Are there issues releated to memory leak ?

```
var can = true;
function dodo() {
    if(can)
    {
        can = false;
        asyncFunc(function(data) {
            doSmth();
            can = true;
        });
    }

}
setInterval(dodo, 0);
```

Comment: well with `setInterval` its going to keep calling it. perhaps you should provide more actual code.

Comment: What is `doSmth`, is that the same as `dodo`?

Comment: Don't use `setInterval` when you want to wait for anything else but the interval.

Comment: @Bergi doSmth is some synchrone code. Let it will var a = 2 + 2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The main idea is I want to call function "dodo" each time after "asyncFunc" is done.

So just call it there:

```
function dodoForever() {
    asyncFunc(function(data) {
        doSmth();
        dodoForever(); // <==
    });
}
dodoForever();
```

You don't need a global `can` state and `setInterval`.

Comment: in this way will I have problem with growing the call stack?

Comment: @user3216941 No, because `asyncFunc` is asynchronous and the callback will run on a new call stack.

Comment: @user3216941 This is what i like to call pseudo recursive. No call stack blowing risk since the internal call to the async function has no way to return anything to a previous stage. It's just a loop making a turn only when the asynch function completes.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call it. Like so.

```
var can = true;
function dodo() {
    if(can)
    {
        can = false;
        asyncFunc(function(data) {
            dodo(); // this will run `dodo` function again.
            doSmth();
            can = true;
        });
    }

}
setInterval(dodo, 0);
```

As the comments mention this will blow the stack up. You have `dodo` running every 0ms. This will basically call `dodo` a TON of times and that is basically all your program will be doing. I can't think of a use case where this would be necessary and it probably won't fair so well in terms of performance.

Really think about why you are trying to run it like that and what the end goal is.

Comment: A word of warning though. This is going to blow the stack up. Since setInterval is calling `dodo` every 0ms (as soon as possible) the first round you have one dodo running, the second round you will have 2 dodo running then 3, 4, 5, 6... within a minute it's possible to have 6000 dodo or more running.

Comment: @slebetman You are 100% correct. Didn't quite notice that. Will edit now.

Comment: @slebetman If I use it without setinterval, and I will call function dodo in itself (like in example Charlie Fish), will I have problem with memory leak? As I understand the count of function will only increases.

Comment: @user3216941 Shouldn’t be a problem so long as it’s not an infinite loop.